# How to draw partial outside of pgf-plot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw arrows on a `pgfplots` plot. For the blue colored arrow everything is fine, but the red and green arrow are not drawn as I'd like. The red arrow tip is cut, the green one is just draw half. I think the problem is, that they are partial outside of the plot. What to do?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,+1.1)},anchor=north},
    xticklabel style = {yshift=0.65cm},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
    y dir=reverse,
    xlabel={x in m},
    ylabel={y in $m$},
    % scale
    x=10cm, y=10cm,z=0cm,
    ymax=1.29, ymin=0,
    xmax=1.59, xmin=0,
    ]
   \addplot[only marks] coordinates {
    (0,0) (0.1,0.00556) (0.2,0.02224) (0.3,0.05004) (0.4,0.08896) (0.5,0.13900) (0.6,0.20016) (0.7,0.27244) (0.8,0.35584) (0.9,0.45036) (1.0,0.55600) (1.1,0.67276)%
    (1.2,0.80064) (1.3,0.9364) (1.4,1.08976) (1.47,1.20146)
 };
 % Boden
 \draw[very thick] (axis cs:0, 1.2) -- (axis cs:1.59, 1.2);
 \draw[->,red,very thick] (0,0) -- (0.3,0);
 \draw[->,blue,very thick] (0.8,0.35584) -- (1.1,0.35584);
 \draw[->,green,very thick] (1.47,1.2) -- (1.77,1.2);
\end{axis}

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Add `clip mode=individual` to the `axis` options

Comment: @Torbjørn T. thats it